# Mongoose aggregate does not work with $or

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a Chat application. My schema looks like this:

```js
{
  from: String,
  to: String,
  message: String,
  attachment: {
    name: String,
    size: Number,
    type: String,
  },
  unread: Boolean,
  sent: Date,
  seen: Date,
}
```

The following code works and returns the latest messages:

**Query 1:**

```js
ChatDB.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    $or: [
      { from, to },
      { from: to, to: from },
    ],
  }},
  { $sort: { sent: -1 }},
  { $limit: messageBatchSize },
  { $sort: { sent: 1 }},
]);
```

But, when I try to paginate by including a timestamp in the query, it does not work anymore:

**Query 2:**

```js
ChatDB.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    sent: { $lt: new Date(beforeTimestamp) },
    $or: [
      { from, to },
      { from: to, to: from },
    ],
  }},
  { $sort: { sent: -1 }},
  { $limit: messageBatchSize },
  { $sort: { sent: 1 }},
]);
```

If I remove the `$or` portion and keep only the timestamp check on `sent`, things work, but (of course) it returns results for all users, which is not what I want:

**Query 3:**

```js
ChatDB.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    sent: { $lt: new Date(beforeTimestamp) },
  }},
  { $sort: { sent: -1 }},
  { $limit: messageBatchSize },
  { $sort: { sent: 1 }},
]);
```

At first I thought it has got to do something with not converting the ids from string to ObjectId and changed my code to use `Types.ObjectId` accordingly. But that did not help even. I mean, **Query 1** works correctly without any conversion.

Any idea what is going on? My `mongoose` version:

```
"mongoose": "^5.8.2",
```

**Edit:**

I tried running the query in mongo console and it returned the results correctly:

```js
> db.chats.aggregate([
...     {
...       $match: {
...         $or: [
...           { from: '5f0319f87278d056876952d5', to: 'org' },
...           { to: '5f0319f87278d056876952d5', from: 'org' },
...         ],
...         sent: { $lt: new Date('2020-07-08T17:05:34.288Z') }
...       }
...     },
...     { $sort: { sent: -1 }},
...     { $limit: 20 },
...     { $sort: { sent: 1 }}
...   ]);
```

Comment: your very first 'or' condition is suspect : "{ from, to }" 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel kinda stupid for posting this in the first place.

The problem turned out to be that the values in `from` and `to` were of type `Types.ObjectId` because they were being retrieved from a different collection.

The values stored in `ChatDB` were strings. Because of this, the query from mongo console worked fine (because I was providing string correctly) and the one with mongoose in the code did not work.

However, I still don't know why **Query 1** worked.